# In Mulesoft Api development, to integrate any application with salesforce do we need to use salesforce connector or http request?

Tags: salesforce, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform

I am using a Mulesoft Salesforce connector for the integration of a system with Salesforce. To achieve it I was calling three-time Salesforce for an operation such as to get assets from Salesforce by using HTTP connector

1. to get token
2. to get salesforce API version
3. the actual rest API call

to avoid three calls I used a Salesforce connector that is easy to configure and easy to use.

My question is here now that what is the best way for it? using HTTP call three times or a salesforce connector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did it using Salesforce connector and in MuleSoft I would say that's the best way to do it. It simplifies the whole process by handling the OAuth token services etc.

As Salesforce bought MuleSoft I believe there will be seemless integration options will come in future. There are many already.

That connector is just a wrapper over those multiple http calls actually.

Comment: Thank you @Lijin,

you are right but is there any difference in terms of performance and response times if we use Salesforce connector?

Comment: We did this an year before in one of our use case. It's pretty fast. no considerable difference.

Comment: Thank you, I will do a POC and will see on that.

Comment: I did a POC and found that the only difference is the ease of development with the salesforce connector and also fewer chances of getting an error 
Also less mess with the connector, as 3 Rest API calls will create more configuration. so we using the connector and replaced all HTTP calls

Comment: If this answer helped you then can you mark it as right answer please? @AnuragSharma